# How to give url path of local file in json

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am trying to display the contents of a txt file **myTutorials.txt**, which is stored on my local disk, using json, But it does not display anything. I just want to know the correct formate of **url "G:/WebTechnologies/myTutorials.txt";**

The code of my web page is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "G:/WebTechnologies/myTutorials.txt";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 
        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923707/using-ajax-to-read-local-files?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you have to prepend file://localhost**

EXAMPLE: `file://localhost/G:/WebTechnologies/myTutorials.txt`

Because of security reasons you will probably have to do 
[loading text file through Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855355/loading-a-text-file-through-ajax-gives-restricted-uri-error)

Answer (score 1):

Reading arbitrary files from the disk is not allowed for security reasons.

In modern browsers you can use the [HTML5 `FileReader` API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) to read files from the disk.