# MapboxGL set visibility based on property from data loaded from file

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to follow an example posted at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/, however in my case, the GeoJSON data is loaded from an external file:

```
map.on('load', function() {
    map.addSource("cacheData", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: "./data.geojson",
```

If I'm following the example, I don't seem to have access to the 'markers' variable to iterate through and add each marker to a layer.

In the original version of Mapbox.js, I am able to enable / disable an individual feature ..  I don't seem to be able to do that the same way in mapboxGL.

Is there an event or something I can use to possibly modify the data as it's being loaded to add each marker from the file to a layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [example from Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/) that you posted, there is `var markers = {}` declaration.  For example,

```
var markers = {
  // properties snipped, see link for GeoJson data
}
```

But in your `map.on()` call, it references `./data.geojson`.  So you don't actually have a `markers` object to work with.

It may be easier to separate the `map.addsource()` from pulling in the GeoJson from disk.

Here is one approach you could using [Jquery](http://jquery.com) to `getJSON` data from a local path or URL first, then you can use the result in `map.on`.

```
    <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js">
      </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var geoJsonFile = "./data.geojson";


      $.getJSON(geoJsonFile, function(markers){

        console.log(markers.type);

      }); // getJSON
    });  // $(document)
```

Comment: Ran into an issue with loading the content from a file (instead of from a server).  Fix at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855355/loading-a-text-file-through-ajax-gives-restricted-uri-error helped.  Thanks!